# How to bring up network on boot-up when NetworkManager is uninstalled?

Tags: networking

I decided to get rid of `network-manager` for some reason, and now in order to get on the network, I have to run `sudo ifup eth0`. Here's what `cat /etc/network/interfaces` gives:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

How do I ensure I don't perform this laborious process again... how do I get the network started automatically on boot-up?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces
```

DHCP

```
# Loopback
#
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# network card
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Static

```
# Loopback
#
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# network card
#
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Restart networking.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

If you use static, you might want to check /etc/resolv.conf to make sure name servers have been specified. It might look like this:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222 # OpenDNS
nameserver 8.8.8.8        # Google
domain example.com
search example.com
```

Comment: [not solved]: 1) vim /etc/network/interfaces; followed your advise 2) rebooted and nothing happens 3) applied ifup eth0 also says "ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0

Comment: My resolv.conf shows nothing (need to boot? It could be in the answer if so.) I did sudo ifup eth0 and at least he didn't complained like before, and still complains with @YumYumYum. But ip link show still says state DOWN for eth0.

Comment: You can verify if adding "allow-hotplug eth0" in "/etc/network/interfaces" also solves the problem in your case. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Add eth0 to `auto lo`, like:

```
auto lo eth0
```

This will bring up lo (loopback) and eth0 on running `ifup -a` (done at boot time).

From `man interfaces`:

> Lines beginning with the word "auto"
>   are used to identify the physical
>   interfaces to be brought up when ifup
>   is run with the  -a  option.
>          (This option is used by the system boot scripts.)  Physical
>   interface names should follow the word
>   "auto" on the same line.  There can be
>          multiple "auto" stanzas.  ifup brings the named interfaces up in the
>   order listed.

Comment: [not solved]: 1) vim /etc/network/interfaces; auto lo eth0 added 2) rebooted and nothing happens 3) applied ifup -a says "ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0

Comment: Great! most of setting static ip tutorials  only tell to add `auto eth0 ....`. But none of them mentions that wouldn't work if there is `auto lo` on top.

Answer (score 4):

this is not helpful if you do not wish to setup an IP address on this interface. 
In my case I wanted to bring up eth0 so it will enter the vswitch config. I had to add the following for the interface in /etc/network/interfaces

```
# eth0 physical, br0 bridge with ovs

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
up ifconfig eth0 up
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: these question is 5 years old and has an accepted answer...

Comment: you want me to delete what i wrote? just say it, dont insinuate it :)

Comment: This helped me.  I wasn't sure if I could make my bridge "auto" also.

Answer (score 1):

> "[not solved]: 1) vim /etc/network/interfaces; followed your advise 2) rebooted and >nothing happens 3) applied ifup eth0 also says "ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0 – >YumYumYum Nov 21 '11 at 20:59"

Today i had the same "ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0" issue.
For me, the problem was due to the fact that I was configuring eth1 (in static) instead of eth0 (I didn't have eth0 configured).

So I just renamed eth1 to eth0 and it worked.

Hoping it could help anyone who done the same mistake.

P.S.: sorry for my bad english, don't hesitate to tell any mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

For people running into this problem and the selected answer isn't working, run `ifconfig -a` to make sure your ethernet device is displayed as `eth0` which is likely the default in your config as well. Mine is `eth1` for whatever reason.

So in `/etc/network/interfaces` I had to use:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback 
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

I also edited `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and set:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Comment: OP said he disabled network manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where ifup ens192 would bring up the interface, but boot or service networking restart would both fail to bring up the ens192 interface ... it was resolved by using only one auto line ...

the new auto line was like this ...

```
auto lo ens192  
iface lo inet loopback  
iface ens192 inet static  
      address x.x.x.x
      etc..etc.etc
###
```

the version that was not working looked like this (where I have two auto lines)

```
auto lo                                                                  
iface lo inet loopback   
auto ens192   
iface ens192 inet static  
   etc...etc..etc.
```